# How do I read an array or variable that is stored in a binary file, and print it out in the program?

Tags: c, file, io, binary

I am having trouble getting values for variables/elements from a file written in another c program to store into the variables/elements of the c program running.
I keep getting segmentation faults when reading the variable "i" into the program (which is an integer that is already determined and stored in the file "inventory.txt"). "i" represents the amount of elements (size) of the arrays being printed. Here is the broken code ): .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int l, k;
    int *pn, *arraysize, *q;
    float *p;
    FILE *fp = fopen( "inventory.txt", "r+b" ); //declarations and I open up the binary file "inventory.txt"

    if ( fp == NULL )
    {                           //check file
        printf( "nah" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    *arraysize = fread( &arraysize, sizeof( int ), 1, fp );     //set arraysize in this program equal to i in the binary file inventory.txt?????? Here is where I get segmentation fault

    printf( "marker1" );        //place marker, I am not getting to this point when running the program

    for ( l = 0; l < *arraysize; l++ )
    {
        q[l] = fread( &q[l], sizeof( int ), arraysize, fp );    //set array elements ("arraysize" of them) pn, q, and p to the array elements of the same name in binary file inventory.txt
        p[l] = fread( &p[l], sizeof( int ), arraysize, fp );
        pn[l] = fread( &pn[l], sizeof( int ), arraysize, fp );
    }

    printf( "Below are the items in your inventory.\nPart#\tQuantity\tPrice\n" );       //print out the values
    for ( l = 0; l < *arraysize; l++ )
    {
        printf( "%5d\t", pn[l] );
        printf( "%8d\t", q[l] );
        printf( "%9.2f\n", p[l] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's some of your code:

```
int *arraysize;
*arraysize=fread(&arraysize,sizeof(int),1,fp);
```

you declare `arraysize` to be an `int *` (a pointer), but then you try to read an int into it.  This makes no sense.  You then try to dereference it to store the return value, which crashes, as it is not a valid pointer.

You likely want

```
int arraysize;
if (fread(&arraysize, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading file\n");
    exit(1); }
```

declaraing `arraysize` as a simple int (not a pointer) and reading into it.

You have similar problems with your other fread calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointers are a bit wrong, the code never allocated any memory to read the values into, and `fread()` returns the number of items read, the code is (for some reason) overwriting the value just read with this result.

Here is a patched version, but you don't include any test data, so it's untested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(  )
{
    int    l;
    int   *pn;
    int   *q;
    float *p;
    int    arraysize;

    FILE *fp = fopen( "inventory.txt", "r+b" ); //declarations and I open up the binary file "inventory.txt"

    if ( fp == NULL )
    {                           //check file
        printf( "nah" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fread( &arraysize, sizeof( int ), 1, fp );     //set arraysize in this program equal to i in the binary file inventory.txt?????? Here is where I get segmentation fault

    printf( "marker1" );        //place marker, I am not getting to this point when running the program


    // Allocate some memory to hold the data (Yes! With cast on malloc())
    q  = (int *)malloc(arraysize * sizeof( int ));  // TODO - check malloc() OK
    pn = (int *)malloc(arraysize * sizeof( int ));  // TODO - check malloc() OK
    p  = (float *)malloc(arraysize * sizeof( float ));  // TODO - check malloc() OK

    // read each entire block in a single operation
    fread( q, sizeof( int ), arraysize, fp );    //set array elements ("arraysize" of them) pn, q, and p to the array elements of the same name in binary file inventory.txt
    fread( p, sizeof( float ), arraysize, fp );
    fread( pn, sizeof( int ), arraysize, fp );


    printf( "Below are the items in your inventory.\nPart#\tQuantity\tPrice\n" );       //print out the values
    for ( l = 0; l < arraysize; l++ )
    {
        printf( "%5d\t", pn[l] );
        printf( "%8d\t", q[l] );
        printf( "%9.2f\n", p[l] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and if you're reading/writing binary values, be sure to handle Endianness if you use different architectures - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness